# Creating menuitems from list with bindings results in blank items

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, menuitem, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a Menuitem which is supposed to show a list of quantities as children which show a list of the units defined for this quantity as children. The list of quantities is set in code-behind to the ItemsSource of the MenuItem.

```
<MenuItem Header="common.unitsystem" Name="mnuItemUnits">
    <MenuItem.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type guidev:Measurement}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Measurement"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type guidev:Quantity}" ItemsSource="{Binding Measurements}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Quantity "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.Resources>
</MenuItem>
```

The result is my MenuItem with a popup, but the subitems (quantities) don't have any bound text on them. The number of subitems is correct, but they have no children themselves. So i suppose there is a problem with the bindings, as the fixed Text i added to check if the DataTemplates actually work is showing ("Quantity").

I think i can't use ItemTemplate for the MenuItem as this is hierarchical with 2 different types...

**EDIT:**

My datamodel looks like this:

```
public class Quantity
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name;

    [XmlElement]
    public List<Measurement> Measurement;
}


public class Measurement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Symbol;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string System;

    public string ToBaseFormula;

    public string FromBaseFormula;
}
```

Comment: Do you really expect us to infer your data model from just the XAML? Please post sufficient information to reproduce the problem, preferably in a standalone mini-application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, glad you asked about the data model... now i figured it out:

The solution is: **Use Properties in the data model, not Fields!**